# Make dropdown list appear ul by ul

Tags: jquery

The dropdown opens all the inner uls at once. I want to open them one by one when the li related to the ul is clicked.

Javascript:

```
$(".first-stage").click(function(e) {
    var $nextItem = $('ul', this);
    var $i = $('i', this);
    $nextItem.slideToggle(function() {
        $i.toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
    });
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3BeGV/3/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have `ul` elements as direct chilren of other `ul`. Only `li` elements may be direct children of a `ul`.

Comment: try this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your markup so it was easier to understand, this is how i would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/3BeGV/6/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>level 1
        <ul class="inner">
            <li>Level 2
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level 2
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level 2
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.main li').on('click',function(e) {
      var target = $( e.target );
       target.children().toggle();
});

$('.inner li').on('click',function(e) {
      var target = $( e.target );
       target.children().toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.inner {
    display:none;
}
```